# Angular UI datepicker giving me a UTC converted string. How to parse it back to local time accounting for the time difference?

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, momentjs

I am currently running into issues with datepicker automatically converting my time to UTC. Is there anything I can pass into datepicker for it to not give me back a UTC converted string? For example the user picks March 19 on the calendar and the returned string would be something like this

```
'2014-03-19T04:00:00.000Z'
```

What I want is ->

```
'2014-03-19T00:00:00-04:00'
```

What I am trying now (sort of hacking around it) is trying to use moment js to convert it back to my desired (expected) format, but I am having trouble doing so without hardcoding a subtraction in there. I want to be able to convert it from UTC back to local time.

Does anyone know of a solution to this using moment js or angular?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564017/how-to-send-angularstrap-datepicker-value-without-timezone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and used a filter that adjusts the date and time using the local data to get around it:

```
filter('adjustDatepicker', ['$filter', function($filter){
    var dateFilter = $filter('date');
    return function(dateToFix){
        var localDate, localTime, localOffset, adjustedDate;

        localDate       = new Date(dateToFix);
        localTime       = localDate.getTime();
        localOffset     = localDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
        adjustedDate    = new Date(localTime + localOffset);

        return dateFilter(adjustedDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy');
    };
}])
```

Use it like this in your template file:

```
{{details.datetomodify | adjustDatepicker}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `new Date('2014-03-19T04:00:00.000Z').toString()` will give you the local version of the UTC time.

[image: time]

Comment: thanks but i need there to be 00 as the hour for my api'2014-03-19T00:00:00'