# Bug timezone in the datepicker of AngularUI?

Tags: php, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui

I use the AngularUI datepicker, it works great.

The only problem is when I select a day such as `2014/05/14`, the value sent is `Wed May 14 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)`.

I sent the value in ajax through `$http({ ... })` and I get the value in a PHP function.

```
<?php 
  echo $day; //2014-05-13T22:00:00.000Z
?>
```

The result is : `2014-05-13T22:00:00.000Z`

I would like : `2014-05-14 00:00.00`

I don't understand, how to solve that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The datepicker will create a timezone local Date object, transforming it to JSON for sending it will convert it to UTC, thus rolling back your 2 hours of GMT+2 over the dateline.

Working with Date can be a bit tricky, I suggest looking into libraries like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)
to be on the safe side when transforming dates and times. By this you can freely define the format of your desired output string.

See also: [How to send AngularStrap datepicker value without timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564017/how-to-send-angularstrap-datepicker-value-without-timezone)